# Convex maximization over the boundary of a convex set

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the objective function that is strictly convex. We would to like maximize $f$ over a convex compact set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that $f$ has a global minima and that $f$ attains global minima at a point outside $S$.

The maximizer(s) of $f$ over such an $S$ seems to lie on the boundary of $S$ as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096812/how-to-show-the-maximizer-of-a-convex-function-lies-on-the-boundary). I believe that the minimizer(s) of $f$ over $S$ also lies on the boundary of $S$.

Does any fast convex minimization algorithm try and check only over the boundary points in this case? Can we find the maximum of $f$ over the boundary efficiently using similar ideas?

**Edit**: My question is: Is there any convex minimization algorithm that proceeds by checking only the values of $f$ at certain chosen points on the boundary of $S$ (when $f$ has a global minima outside $S$)? I am thinking of an algorithm like the simplex algorithm, in linear programming, that checks the values of $f$ at certain chosen points on the boundary of $S$. Contrast this with the the interior point method, that checks values of $f$ at points even *inside* $S$.

If there were such an algorithm, I am wondering why we can't use similar ideas as that used in the algorithm to maximize $f$ over the boundary of $S$.

Comment: Welcome to MO!  Not sure if this question fits MO as well as it would MSE, but  it seems intuitive that the points $x$ in $S$ where $f(x)-f(x^*)$ is smallest will lie on $\partial S$.

Comment: Hi! I guess my question is why is there no fast (polynomial time) algorithm for maximizing a convex function $f$ over a compact convex set $S$? Or is there one?

Comment: Your problem is not a _convex_ minimization problem, but a _concave_ minimization problem. Minimizing a (strictly) convex function is easy, since the minimum is unique. Minimizing a concave function is apparently NP hard. There are some numerical algorithms if you google "Concave programming" or "Concave minimization".